# Cant find laravel running in port 8000

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I was creating docker container for laravel with postgres. containers running but cant find laravel in web.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 8000
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  php_3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  postgres_3:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: lara_3
```

Without error both services are running but cant find laravel runnning in browser. what i want to change.please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In Dockerfile instead of

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`

write:

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80`

and EXPOSE 80

Comment: Tried didn't work.

Comment: also check this `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

Comment: same issue with --port=8000

Answer (score 0):

When you install php-fpm what you get is a server process, and then you need to config nginx to forward all requests to php files to be parsed by this php-fpm process.

Alternatively you can install php-apache docker image that include the apache server.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  php_3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  postgres_3:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: lara_3
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

**conf/nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php_3:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this all containers are running but i can't see laravel running in localhost:8000 after that i added CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 in dockerfile and that also not giving any solution.